# How do I integrate an MPC, PID and System models together to simulate on Matlab

Tags: matlab, controls, modeling

I have a system with a Model Predictive Controller and PID Controller. 
Assuming I have models for each controller and can express them in discrete time, please how do I integrate them together to simulate properties of the system in matlab?

Thanks

Comment: in what form do you have your MPC controller? as transfer function? state space system? MPC object? Both your questions are well documented in the documentation to your toolbox. So where exactly do you get stucked, what have you tried? In Simulink you can find blocks for both, discrete PID controller and MPC controller.

Comment: I have the system model as a transfer function, PID also in transfer function but i'm struggling to generate the TF for the MPC Controller. Do you suggest it would be much easier to use Simulink to solve the problem? 
I am new to simulink so any tips on how to go about generating blocks?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... continuing from the comments. 
This is what Simulink is made for. Of course there are ways to do it without Simulink, but often you still use Simulink tools and functions just without the graphical Interface.

I assume you have your transfer functions "on paper". So you need the `tf` function to define your system model.

```
G = tf(num,den)
```

`num` and `den` are the coefficient vectors of your transfer function of numerator and denumerator. In Simulink you use the `Transfer Fcn` block and you define it with

```
G.num{1} %Numerator coefficients
G.den{1} %Denumerator coefficients
```

Your PID-controller cannot be defined using this block, as Simulink requires a higher or equal order for the denumerator. Instead use the `PID controller` Block. You need to calculate the Proportional, Integral and Differential gain before.

Then read the [documentation about the MPC toolbox](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/mpc/index.html) - I'm not familiar with it and can't help you on that - it is explained how you can create an `mpc object` regarding all your constraints (see your other question).

Then you have [various options](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/mpc/analysis.html) to transform your mpc object into something Simulink can deal with. I'd recommend the `ss` - the state space model - which can be implemented using the `state space` block. There is also a `MPC Controller` block, I don't have the toolbox - but you'll be able to find out how it can be used.

Finally you find source blocks, like a `step` to generate a test signal. And there are `Sinks`, in the easiest case `scope` to display your results. You can also save them to workspace or whatever...

Comment: Gracias! Will get on with it and watch a couple of videos on how to use the toolboxes. Hopefully I would be able to put all the info together.